# How to display canvas coordinates when hovering cursor over canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I hover over the canvas I want some labels on top of the canvas to display x,y coordinates which stay the same if I keep my cursor still but change when I move it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a callback method and bind it to a [`Motion` event](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-types.html).

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

def moved(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure(tag, text="(%r, %r)" % (event.x, event.y))

canvas.bind("<Motion>", moved)
tag = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text="", anchor="nw")  

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Also use `<Enter>` event. So when you switch between windows (`<Alt>+<Tab>` hotkey), your cursor will show the correct coordinates.

For example, you put your cursor on the canvas and `<Motion>` event will track it, but when you press `<Alt>+<Tab>` and switch to another window, then move your cursor a bit and `<Alt>+<Tab>` on your canvas again -- coordinates of the your cursor will be wrong, because `<Motion>` event doesn't track switches between windows. To fix it use `<Enter>` event.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

def get_coordinates(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure(tag, text='({x}, {y})'.format(x=event.x, y=event.y))

canvas.bind('<Motion>', get_coordinates)
canvas.bind('<Enter>', get_coordinates)  # handle <Alt>+<Tab> switches between windows
tag = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text='', anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
```